# MySQL - Avoid repeating of result rows (with SUM)

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with a query:

```
SELECT intracee, descr_intra, SUM(quanti) AS quan, SUM(pesotot) AS pesot, SUM(importo) AS impo FROM ".$gaDB."001intramov
                    WHERE datmov BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-07-20' GROUP BY intracee
```

The target is, to select (with a form) every row between two dates and sum values grouping by the "intracee" code number and then print report with tcpdf.
It's actually working good, the problem is that repeats result rows again and again.

Here's a screenshot of DB table:

[image]

And here's one of result:

[image]

I just need to avoid the infinite repeating of result rows.
The result, in this case, should be the first two rows only.

I tried LIMIT and also with subquery, but the result is exactly the same!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try adding descr_intra to the group by clause.

Comment: I get the same result...

Comment: Where do you execute this code? On the MySQL CLI, phpMyAdmin, specific PHP page? You tagged it mysqli, so I suppose it's a PHP page? To me, it seems that the query is executed multiple times. Is the list really infinite, or does it stop after a certain number of rows? If it's PHP, can you please show some more code how you execute the query?

Comment: Where do you check the result? At my side it works as expected. do you have any joins in the query? It looks incomplete  - FROM ".$gaDB."001intramov - missing double quote in the name of the table.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem:

I forgot to delete the query where the query I posted was included.

Ispirer SQLWays Migrations helped me asking if I have any join, then I saw the mistake.

```
$cod = gaz_dbi_dyn_query("*", $gaDB."intracee","");
while ($c = gaz_dbi_fetch_array($cod)) {            

$dati = gaz_dbi_query("SELECT intracee, descr_intra, SUM(quanti) AS quan, SUM(pesotot) AS pesot, SUM(importo) AS impo FROM ".$gaDB."001intramov
                    WHERE datmov BETWEEN ".$date_ini." AND ".$date_fin." GROUP BY intracee,descr_intra");
while ($r = gaz_dbi_fetch_array($dati)) {
  $pdf->Cell(70,6,$r['intracee'].' - '.$r['descr_intra'],1);
  $pdf->Cell(40,6,$r['quan'],1,0,'C');
  $pdf->Cell(40,6,gaz_format_number($r['pesot'],2),1,0,'C');
  $pdf->Cell(40,6,gaz_format_number($r['impo'],2),1,0,'C');
  $pdf->Ln();
}
```

}

Thank you for helping me, and sorry for wasting your time for something easy as this.
Too many hours working, and the become really hard to find some details!